# Invariant generalized sections of dual vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, differential-topology, vector-bundles, topological-vector-spaces

Assume X is a real smooth manifold with an action of the real Lie group G. Let E be a G-vector bundle over X. Consider the spaces of generalized sections over X of E, and of E^* (fiberwise dual). My question is: do the spaces of G-invariants of those two spaces have equal dimension?
Of course one should assume something about the nature of the action of G on X, in particular so that both dimensions are finite. If G acts transitively, an invariant secion is automatically smooth, and this is a correct and easy statement . What if G acts with finitely many orbits which are geometrically reasonable? What if we are in an algebraic variety-algebraic group setting?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean in your last sentence, but in the setting of algebraic geometry this is definitely false : a very ample line bundle has a lot of sections while its dual has none.

Comment: Could you please give an example over the reals?

Comment: Take the projective space and the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is the group $G$ in this example?

Comment: The trivial group.

Comment: Then the spaces of generalized (or smooth) sections are infinite dimensional. I don't require them to be non-vanishing or something.

Comment: I am talking about algebraic geometry, hence algebraic sections.